# changing/stripping off url pointed by image using javascript

Tags: javascript

Might be a very simple javascript injection question, but say I have an image html tag:

```
<a href="myfile.htm"><img src="rainbow.gif"></a>
```

I wanted to perform a javascript, such that when clicked on the image, it doesn't go to the myfile.htm. In other words, I wanted to strip the a href which surrounds the img. How can I do this in javascript? Say that I have the following to reference the image tag:

```
document.elementFromPoint(%f, %f)
```

f can be replaced by any double/float value

Comment: I am not sure how the second half of your question has anything to do with the first. I have followed up to the point when you asked about stripping the href from the anchor using javascript (which is possible), but then you started talking about some double/float values where I lost your line of thoughts.

Comment: oh just ignore the double/floats, I am just saying that the way I get the image tag is by using elementFromPoint function, that's all.. ignore the f stuff if that confuses you

Answer (score 2):

If you have a reference to the `img` element, then its parent (`parentNode`) will be the link (in the structure you've given). Three options:

1. Remove the link entirely
2. Disable the link
3. Change the link's `href`

#### 1. Remove the link entirely

You can remove the link entirely by doing this:

```
var link       = img.parentNode,
    linkParent = link.parentNode;
linkParent.insertBefore(img, link);
linkParent.removeChild(link);
```

That uses [`parentNode`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-1060184317) to find the parent and grandparent, [`insertBefore`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-952280727) to move the image, and [`removeChild`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-1734834066) to remove the link. Note that this assumes the image is the only thing in the link.

#### 2. Disable the link

If you want to keep the link but render it useless, you can do this:

```
var link = img.parentNode;
if (link.addEventListener) {
    link.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }, false);
}
else if (link.attachEvent) {
    link.attachEvent("onclick", function() {
        return false;
    });
}
else {
    link.onclick = function() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

#### 3. Change the `href` of the link:

This is trivial, just set the `href` property of the link element (which you can get because it's the parent node of the image) to whatever you want:

```
img.parentNode.href = /* ...something else */;
```

For instance:

```
img.parentNode.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
```

...would change the link to point to Stack Overflow.

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/epuwoy)

---

Some references:

- [DOM2 Core](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/)
- [DOM2 HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/)
- [DOM3 Core](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/)
- [HTML5 Web Application APIs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/#auto-toc-6)

Comment: so var parent here is the <a href> tag? what is gran then?

Comment: @adit: Yes, `img.parentNode` would be the link in the structure you've quoted. `gran` would be whatever the parent element of the link is. I've changed the names to be a bit clearer. The DOM is a bit convoluted, to remove an element you have to have a reference to its parent. I've added two other options for you, btw, in case you don't actually want to remove the link.

Comment: @adit: I think your comment was cut off.

Comment: +1 -- I didn't know you could return false from `foo.onclick = function() { return false };` and have the default action be prevented.  I thought that only worked with dom level zero handlers:  `<a onclick = "return false"`

Comment: @AdamRackis: Yeah, I looked into this a while back: http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/11/story-on-return-false.html

Comment: for some reason just assigning the href to some string doesnt work for me

Comment: @adit: There must be some problem elsewhere, fundamentally that works (I assume you're talking about option 3). I've added a live example.

Answer (score 1):

```
<a id="anchorWithImage" href="myfile.htm"><img src="rainbow.gif"></a>
```

Why not grab the anchor, then set its href to nothing:

```
var a = document.getElementById("anchorWithImage");
a.href = "javascript:void(0)";
```

Or grab it and set its click event to cancel the default action, which is to browse to the location of its href property

```
a.onclick = function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
}
```

---

Or do you want to grab all anchors that have an image as their child element, and strip out their href?

jQuery would make this easy, if that's an option for you

```
$("a").filter(function() {
    return $(this).children("a").length === 1;
}).attr("href", "javascript:void(0)");
```

or

```
$("a").filter(function() {
    return $(this).children("a").length === 1;
}).click(function() { return false; });  //returning false from jQuery handlers
                                         //prevents the default action
```

---

**EDIT**

If you were to have a reference to the image, and wanted to set its parent's anchor's href, you'd grab it with the parentNode property:

```
var img = document.getElementById("imgId");
var a = img.parentNode;
a.href = "javascript:void(0)";
```

Comment: how do I grab the anchor if I only have a reference to the <img> tag?

Comment: is setAttribute a javascript or jquery function?

Comment: @adit - it's a pure JavaScript function - not jQuery

Comment: `setAttribute("href", "#")` has the side effect of scrolling to the top of the page. `setAttribute("href", "javascript:")` is more innocuous.

Comment: Hey Adam - Note that `HTMLAnchorElement` instances have [an `href` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-48250443) you can set directly, no need to use `setAttribute`.

Comment: Thanks @T.J.Crowder - that's probably a good idea since I've heard setAttribute is not treated well in older versions of IE

Answer (score 0):

you can change the href of a tag on window load itself, so you need not worry when it is clicked.

```
window.onload = fundtion(){
var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
 for(var i=0;i<imgs.length;i++){
   var parentElem = imgs[i].parentNode;
   if(parentElem.tagName === 'A') 
   parentElem.setAttribute("href", "javascript:void(0)");
 }
};
```

Comment: I actually just wanted to change the href to "no-link"

Comment: you want to do that on click of image only or its fine vanishing the link on page load itself???

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery you could use something similar to this

```
$("a").has("img").click(function(e).preventDefaults();});
```

Basically all this line does is identifies all  tags within the document containing an  tag disables standard event process

Answer (score 0):

From your comment on another answer, it sounds like you actually want to change/eliminate the target of links at a specific position in the page.  You could do something like this:

```
var el = document.elementFromPoint(10, 10);

while(el) {
    if(el.nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'a')
        el.href = 'javascript:';

    el = el.parentElement;
}
```

This would loop up from the selected element, identify if the element is an anchor, and set the `href` to something that does nothing.